# rsync remove only some file extensions from source after syncing

Tags: rsync

On my local machine I have some directories (with subdirectories) with many files (`jpeg` and `nef`), like:

```
1.jpg
1.nef
2.jpg
2.nef
....
```

what I want to do is to sync on an HD all files (both `jpeg` and `nef`) but after syncing, deleting on my local computer only the `nef` files and keep the `jpg`.

Is there a way to combine this with `--remove-source-files`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For safety, I would delete the `.nef` files in a separate step after using `rsync` to transfer both types of files. For example, like this:

```
rsync --verbose --archive --prune-empty-dirs \
    --include='*.nef' \
    --include='*.jpg' \
    --include='*/' \
    --exclude='*' \
    "$source/" "$target"

find "$source" -type f -name '*.nef' -delete
```

The `rsync` command here would only copy the `.nef` and `.jpg` files (it would skip any other file, and it would not create empty directories at `$target` due to `--prune-empty-dirs`), and then the `find` command would delete all `.nef` files.

I tend to never use `--remove-source-files` with `rsync`.

Comment: why `--include='*/' \ ` and `--exclude='*' \ `? BTW it seems a good solution.

Comment: @matteo I only want to copy the files with the given filename suffixes, which is why I use `--exclude='*'` to exclude all other files (note that I know nothing about what else you have in your source directory). To be able to recurse, I still have to include directories (these would be excluded by `--exclude='*'`), which is why I also have `--include='*/'`.

Answer (score 1):

We may need to sync twice since we dont have option to exclude source-delete.

Try as,

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files --exclude='*.jpg' Source/ Destination ; rsync -av Source/*.jpg Destination
```